# How to open the fast a large PDF file from Amazon bucket s3 in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, react-pdf

I have solve  cors issue  from S3 bucket . it is my cors settings

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

1. I have  used  react-pdf  library. but it has  occured  pdf loaded without error.
2. I have  used  react-pdf-js-infinite library . It has been working but. I has been very slowly opening  pdf  file.

3.I have  used  iframe. it has been  working only firefox. but Chrome has not been working.

```
  <object
            data={this.state.file}
            type="application/pdf"
            width="100%"
            height="600"
            style={{overflow:"unset"}}
          >
    
            <iframe
             sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms"
             title="PortletIFrameWidget"
             src={this.state.file}
             ref={(f) => { this.ifr = f }}
              width="500"
              height="678"
            >
            </iframe>
```

4. I have used  by

   this.url = 'https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=' +tempfile+ 'this.state.file+&hl=en&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true';
   for  iframe .  It has occured  large  file  failed  error

How   to solve  problem other way?

Comment: What’s the size of the file?

Comment: it is aproximately 30 mb

Comment: @SanishJoseph do you have  other solution?

Comment: Not for browsers. Check the explanation in this link. You should try some server rendering options. https://www.pdftron.com/blog/guide/how-to-display-2-gb-files/